# Opening C# WinForm via keyboard intercept not getting focus

Tags: keyboard, focus, intercept

I'm using standard approaches to intercept a certain key combination in order to display a form (a requirement for my app) that has a text box in a MenuStrip (not ContextMenuStrip). My form gets the focus in all cases except when Microsoft Word is open when I press the keys to open the form, it does not. The toggle of the TopMost property came from another post and appears to have helped in most cases.

from the form that intercepts the keystrokes:

```
StartMenuPopup.Show();
StartMenuPopup.TopMost = true;
StartMenuPopup.TopMost = false;
StartMenuPopup.TopMost = true;  //tried leaving this out
StartMenuPopup.Activate();
```

the Load event handler of the form I want to have the focus. Yes I know this is redundant code and shouldn't be necessary but I am looking for some combination that works. So far this is my best shot after trying dozens of approaches.

```
private void StartMenuPopup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.Activate();
        this.Focus();
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.TopMost = false;
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

If you want to see the app to repro, it's called SmartMenu (formerly StartGen) at http://BrainDance.co. I am getting the impression that some apps like Word are doing their own keyboard intercepts which are somehow interfere with my keyboard intercepts. My latest attempt shown above solved the problem with PowerPoint and other apps. Just not Microsoft Word. I have seen some approaches suggested that came with the caveat that they were not good programming practices and were indicative of bad design. No need to suggest any "bad" approaches as I won't use them.

More details. The keystroke intercepts are done in a separate DLL which I bundle into a single exe when the code is obfuscated. I could move the code into the exe assembly but given that it is all running as one assembly after install, I don't think that would be the cause here.